# internet explorer (edge) double-rendering of jquery appends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a baffling issue with how IE (Edge) is rendering my simple, jquery-driven page. Every once in a while (maybe 1 in 20 page loads), I encounter an IE-only issue where the page renders rows of identical table content twice per row. For example, a 50-row table will be rendered as 100 rows, where rows 1 & 2 are identical, rows 3 & 4 are identical, etc. Moreover, every table on the page will have the same issue. I'm using jquery to do the content-tweaking and display, but nothing out of the very ordinary. Things like .append(), .html(), etc.

Has anyone ever encountered this IE bug? If so, can you send me info on how to find out more. (For example, what is the rendering bug named? Many thanks.

Comment: Oh, my bad. It is IE11. In Developer Tools, it says the document mode is "Edge"

Comment: yeah, IE11 in IE11 mode (as opposed to earlier emulation modes) is called Edge - so, thanks microsoft for a source of confusion :p

Comment: @Ringo - perhaps you could supply an example of code that demonstrates this apparent issue - without seeing what you are doing, we can only guess